# Активация модального окна Bootstrap

Tags: php, bootstrap4

Как сделать чтобы при перегрузке страницы по срабатыванию условия в PHP окно активировалось. Например в условии

```
if($_POST){ 
}
```

Ниже пример из руководства Bootstrap 4 с активацией окна по кнопке.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Запустить модальное окно
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Я вывожу таблицу с кнопкой перед каждой записью и хочу чтобы по нажатию кнопки открывалось модальное окно на редактирование. У меня не получается, наверно потому что атрибут type="submit" а для bootstrapa нужно "button".

```
    <form action="" method="post"">
    <table class="table-sm table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead class="table-success sticky-top">
            <?php 
            $zag = array (' ','Код','Тип','Описание');
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach($zag as $key => $value) {
                echo '<th scope="col">'."$value"."</th>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
            ?>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            for ($row_no = 0; $row_no <= $res->num_rows - 1; $row_no++) {
                $res->data_seek($row_no);
                $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
                echo '<tr class=" m-0 p-0">';
                echo '<td> <input type="radio" name="raz"/>'.$row[id].' </td>';
                 echo '<td> <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" name="but1" value="'.$row[id].'" >'.$row[id].'</button> </td>';                  
                foreach($row as $key => $value) {
                    echo '<td>'." $value </td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
             $res->free(); 
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Немного криво, но должно работать. Если есть условие, просто выводим js скрипт, который нажимает на кнопку.

```html
if($_POST){
  echo ' 
<button type="button" id="buttonID" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Запустить модальное окно
</button>
<script>
$("#buttonID").click();
</script>';
}
```

Comment: а зачем Вы взяли мой ответ и добавили в свой?

Comment: @humster_spb вы не правы. в данном ответе добавлено условие пхп и вывод скрипта в нем. у вас этого нет, и вы не поняли о чем речь. автор же сего ответа понял.

Comment: @teran, у автора ответа изначально не было варианта "или" с конструкцией $('#myModal').modal('show') - он его добавил после того, как увидел мой ответ. Вы считаете, это корректно? Его вариант с click() работать не будет

Comment: Суть в том, что бы дать точный ответ на поставленный вопрос, у Вас не было условия, у меня правильного открытия модального окна, в итоге - автор получил нужный ответ

Comment: Про условие у меня всё сказано внизу ответа. Никакого условия у автора нет - if($_POST) просто так не отработает, этот скрипт на сервере надо чем-то запускать, отправлять туда какой-то запрос.

Comment: Убрал ваше решение из ответа

Comment: Я бы вызов модального окна обернул в $( document ).ready(function() {     }); Так как на момент вызова - модальное окно должно быть полностью загружено, включая его обработчики.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще за активацию модального окна в Бутстрапе (в том числе после перезагрузки страницы) отвечает конструкция `$('#myModal').modal('show')`:

```js
$('#myModal').modal('show')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

А вот что значит *по срабатыванию условия в PHP* - не очень ясно. Чтобы какой-то php-код отработал на сервере и что-то вернул клиенту, его надо как-то запустить - то есть отправить на сервер запрос. Чем, как и какой именно запрос Вы отправляете?

Comment: Я вывожу записи таблицы на экран и перед каждой записью хочу сделать кнопки редактировать / удалить.  При нажатии на редактирование должно открыться модальное окно с данными  записи таблицы для редактирования.  Может что то не так делал. Не получалось вызвать по кнопке модальное окно и передать туда айди записи.